# import struct in go, get "not a type" error

Tags: go, struct

I import a struct defined in another package, when try to use it to construct a literal, get a "not a type" error.

In publish.go

```
type Book struct {
    Name string
    Author string
    Published bool
}
```

In store.go

```
import "publish"

func Init() {
    var reading publish.Book

    b := &reading {
        Name: "Learn Go Lang",
        Author: "Rob",
        Published: true
    }
}
```

Error: reading is not a type

Answer (score 4):

Here you try to make a struct of Type "reading"

```
b := &reading {
       Name: "Learn Go Lang",
       Author: "Rob",
       Published: true
    }
```

What you want is a struct of type publish.Book

```
b := & publish.Book {
       Name: "Learn Go Lang",
       Author: "Rob",
       Published: true,
    }
```

plus you also need a comma at the end of the last in a multi-line struct declaration.

Comment: Hi Ben, Thanks for the response. Yes, directly use &publish.Book{...} works. But I'm wondering why I cannot make a local instance: var reading publish.Book, and then &reading{...} ??

Comment: var reading publish.Book declares a variable of Book, it doesn't create an alias of that type. If you want you can assign to the elements of reading using reading.Name = "Learn Go Lang" etc...

Comment: what does "a variable of Book" mean? if it does not equivalent to alias or instance of that type?

Comment: alias and instance are not equivalent. An Alias is a renaming of a type. You can have multiple instances of the same type. (I meant a variable of type book).